# PlayStation 4 from UK to India will I have to pay customs duty?

Tags: india, electronic-items, import-taxes

I bought a PS4 in UK and I've been using it for close to two and a half weeks here and I'm taking it back to India so will I have to pay them? There are no boxes, just the console in one suitcase wrapped in a blanket and the controller in another suitcase.

If I do get stopped how much will I have to pay? The total price I paid was around 38k including a game and the console.

Comment: Are you moving from the UK to India, or were you just in the UK on vacation when you bought it? That will probably change the answer (at least I know it would in many countries), and will also affect whether this question is on-topic here.

Comment: I was on a vacation in the UK for a while. I bought it there and I've actually been using it so I'm thinking I should be fine. The console costs exactly £349 which comes to less than 35,000 rupees. That excludes the 3 pound delivery charge.

Answer (score 0):

According to [importdutycalculator.com](http://www.dutycalculator.com/country-guides/Import-duty-taxes-when-importing-into-India), electronics are never subject to Indian import duties:

> Duty rates in India can be ad valorem (as a percentage of value) or specific (rupees per unit).  Duty rates vary from 0% to 150%, with an average duty rate of 11.9%.  **Some goods are not subject to duty (e.g. laptops and other electronic products).**

So you shouldn't be required to pay an import duty on your PS4, even if you were bringing it into the country to resell.

Comment: That website is incorrect. There's a duty-free limit of Rs 35,000 on *all* imports including electronics, with 36.05% slapped on top if you exceed this.  See: http://www.cbec.gov.in/trvler-guide_ason22may2013.pdf

Comment: @jpatokal: That doesn't appear to contradict the site I quoted (but it also doesn't corroborate it)... but I haven't read the entire document. If you have better information, I encourage you to provide a new answer.